# SVN unversioned directory of same name already exists

Tags: svn

I have an SVN repository that is worked on by a few people and has working copies checked out in multiple deployments. There was a directory where the contents were ignored. One of the subdirectories of this directory needed a file to be added to version control so I added the file and ignored all the others.

When I update the working copies in other locations I get this error

`svn: Failed to add directory 'XXXX': an unversioned directory of the same name already exists`

Is there some way I can either keep this new file versioned without re-creating the repository and checking out each and every working copy again?

Or is there a way I can roll back to before I added this file to version control?

Or is there another way of getting this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having spent a lot of time researching this I tried a few things, the solution that worked quite well was to run

`svn merge -r 1187:1182 <working copy path>`

where 1187 was the revision I was at and 1182 was the revision I wanted to roll back to.